# Can't use recur in multi-arity Clojure function

Tags: clojure

This works:

```
(defn tri*
  ([] (tri* 0 1))
  ([sum n]
   (let [new-sum (+ sum n)]
     (cons new-sum (lazy-seq (tri* new-sum (+ n 1)))))))
```

but when I use `recur` in it, I get a `CompilerException`:

> Mismatched argument count to recur, expected 0 args, got: 2

```
(defn tri*
  ([] (tri* 0 1))
  ([sum n]
   (let [new-sum (+ sum n)]
     (cons new-sum (lazy-seq (recur new-sum (+ n 1)))))))
```

Comment: The problem is not arity. Your `recur` is surrounded by `lazy-seq` and `cons`, hence is not in tail position.

Comment: @Thumbnail Interestingly for this problem, while it looks like the `recur` is not in tail position, after macro expansion, it is. Thus the confusing compiler diagnostic instead of `Can only recur from tail position`.

Comment: @MikeFikes The `recur` is not in tail position for  `tri*`.

Comment: @Thumbnail Right. After macroexpansion, `recur` is in tail position for `fn*`. Hence the “mismatched argument count” error (the `fn*` form takes zero args) instead of a “can only recur from tail position” error.

Comment: @Thumbnail Thanks! I've edited the answer, hopefully improving it with your suggestion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`lazy-seq` is a macro which expands to code involving a zero-arg thunk that can be called later as the sequence is realized. You can see that the `recur` form is captured as the body of this thunk by doing

```
(macroexpand '(lazy-seq (recur new-sum (+ n 1))))
```

to get

```
(new clojure.lang.LazySeq (fn* [] (recur new-sum (+ n 1))))
```

which shows that the target of `recur` is the thunk, not `tri*`.

Another way to think about all of this is that the original call to `tri*` has long since completed (and returned a `Cons` object containing `LazySeq` rest object) by the time `recur` would be “evaluated.”

Your first version of `tri*` is fine in that the recursive call to `tri*` doesn't grow the stack, but instead simply creates a new set of `Cons` / `LazySeq` objects.